# Printing QStringList in gdb

Tags: debugging, qt4, gdb, pretty-print

I am using [kde-devel-gdb](http://randomguy3.wordpress.com/2008/05/12/printing-qstrings-in-gdb/) script for printing QT typed variables. I am able to print **QString** using the script but not **QStringList** as it is showing:

> gdb-internal-error: findvar.c (...): type is not a pointer or
>   reference

My development environment is HP-UX (32 bit)

Do anybody knows pretty printers for HP-UX gdb to print Qt typed variables.